Can you skip drywall taping coats 2+ and just skim coat after embedding tape and letting dry?
I am fairly new to drywall and have watched alot of youtube videos learning. What i have is battens in a mobile home which i am using mesh tape and 90 minute easy sand to fill over VOG, about 3,000 sq ft of walls. My question, with the final intent to skim coat with a uniform surface being the end goal, could I simply not just embed the mesh tape, let dry, and then skim coat, effectively skipping coats 2+ for feathering the joints? To go through all the work to apply multiple coats with sanding and scraping and feathering to just skim coat seems inefficient to me. Seems like for a beginner it would just be easier to do it this way.

To clarify, you are intending to skim coat over vinyl coated panels?

You are correct.

You can do that, but you will soon see that you will have to deal with these consequences:

A thick layer of drywall compound will take a very long time to dry. Even if you are using hot mud, it will get hard, but it won't be ready to sand. Even if just a little bit is wet, it will clog your sandpaper and get damaged in the process. So by trying to take days off, you will be adding several days of waiting between coats.

Because you will be trying to do it in a single coat, you will end up putting too much in some areas and too little in others. The areas with too much will take you forever to sand down, the areas with too little will require more coats, negating the whole purpose of the single thick coat.

Cold mud will take forever to dry -- even a week -- if applied in thick layers, but if applied in thin layers, will dry quickly and will be super easy to sand off. Hot mud is a lot harder to sand, regardless if the bag says "Easy Sand" or not.

No matter how good you get at it, touchoup is always necessary.


This is why good finishers working with large areas split the work into taping, filling, then 2 feathering coats. When you add up the hours, it's easier and takes less time, and the result looks better.

Thank you for your answer. I typically get time to work on this about twice a week or every 3-4 days for 4-8 hours each time so waiting between coats isnt a huge concern. Ill move in when the work is completed.

I don't know if I totally agree with mudding over vinyl.   There are a few risks here long term I have.

what is the ceiling made out of?   Can you meet up with with the ceiling without it looking like a crack?
the flex of vinyl walling I have seen is way more than drywall.    This doesn't bode well of large skim coats.   Without reinforcing it I would try a 10-20ft section first.
I would be worried about the adhesion between the finished vinyl and joint compound.   I think at a minimum you would go over the entire wall with an oil based primer to just totally shield the vinyl - and moisture going through it.

As far as how you do it, it isn't hard it is just very labor intensive.

Use paper tape and put your first coat on.
Do not use quick dry (even 2 hour) joint compound.   Get light weight joint compound and you will mix up about a half bucket at a time (so you need an extra bucket).    You will add a little dish soap, lots of water and paddle mix it until it is consistency of pancake syrup.
You will use a 3/4" nap paint roller.   The roller barely fit in the bucket.   Dip it and apply to wall.    You will need to hit each wall section a few times to get good coverage.
Once you cover an area you will go over it with a 12-18" mud knife.    This is just practice.   The first coat takes a while.   (why I said no quick dry is unless you have a few helpers by the time you are done with your half bucket, it starts getting thick and harder to apply with quick dry the bottom couple inches will be unusable)
Light sand after first coat.  (first coat is 3 days drying time)
Same steps for the second coat.    I have had guys in my crew try to spot fix after the first coat with knife/trowel...    This is much much slower.   The second coat goes on in 1/4th the time and the knife work is easier.   Trying to spot fix things leaves more ridges and things you don't see.

